# I don't want my c# script looks like a DDOS attack

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, ddos

I have a large .net core website with a caching feature (last 24h). I would like to code a window service to open x pages early on the morning, in order to force them in cache.
But I am worried about firing the DDOS protection from my hosting provider (I have dedicated serveur, but I use DDOS protection on it).

Do you have any ideas about it ? I thought visiting x pages and wait 1 minutes before the next bundle. But how can I estimate the maximum number of pages ? Is it about frequency (x pages per secondes) or about total weight (x Mb per seconds) ?

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: White list the machine that will be doing the requests

Comment: Launch a script locally on the machine that hosts the app

Comment: That was my intention but I didn't know if it will be enough. Do I understand well : if I run a program locally on the machine that hosts the app, they will share the same IP so my hosting provider won't identify my as a hacker, EVEN IF my script call a browser to load pages ? I thought using  Process.Start(myUrl); which launches the default browser on the web server. Is there a better option than Process.Start ?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thanks for the advice. My cache is 24 hours, and my website is a directory with many changes day to day (made by customers wich have the profiles on the directory). I must refresh the changes after 24h or they won't be happy...

Comment: You do not need to call a browser. Use httprequests instead.